# java dates conversion with 00:00:00.000

Tags: java, date, datetime

I have date strings in this format:

```
2011/02/14 00:00:00.000 -0800
```

I convert it to java Date object in the following way:

```
this.pubDate = Date.parse("yyyy/MM/dd 00:00:00.000 Z", obj.SourcePublishedDate);
```

The above produces result 2011/02/14 00:00:00.000 +0000
I have two questions about the result. With parsing 0 time as it is, I'm using format "yyyy/MM/dd 00:00:00.000 Z". Is there a better way to do that, maintaining the 0s?   The second question is about the timezone, for some reason I'm getting back +0000 instead of -0800. How could parse the right value?
Much appreciate your time.

Comment: What is `Date.parse()`?

Comment: This Question is more interesting than it may seem at first glance. One might be in a situation where they expect date-time values that always represent the first moment of the day. And so, naïvely, they assume that time-of-day to always be all-zeros. Given that assumption, you might intuitively think of hard-coding the all-zeros time-of-day. Hard-coding zeros does not work for a couple of reasons discussed in [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35952752/642706). More importantly, I say ‘naïve’ because the first moment of the day is *not* always `00:00:00.000`. Anyways, interesting.

Answer (score 2):

1. java Date can't include TimeZone information.
2. If you have to use Java 7  or less. You can use Java Calendar
3. If you use Java 8+. You can use OffsetDateTime to store both date/time & time zone

   ```
   // Parser
   DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS Z");

   // Parse date/time with time zone
   // OffsetDateTime odtWithTime = OffsetDateTime.parse("2011/02/14 00:00:00.000 -0800", formatter);
   OffsetDateTime odtWithTime = OffsetDateTime.parse("2011/02/14 09:30:00.999 -0800", formatter);

   // odtWithTime: 2011-02-14T09:30:00.999-08:00

   // Remove time from odtWithTime
   LocalDateTime ldtWithoutTime = odtWithTime.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay();
   OffsetDateTime odtWihtoutTime = OffsetDateTime.of(ldtWithoutTime, odtWithTime.getOffset());

   // odtWihtoutTime: 2011-02-14T00:00-08:00
   // All time information are reset to Zero
   ```

**Summary**: You parse date/time & timezone then reset all time information to Zero.

Comment: Thank you, so it seems like there is no way to parse 0 time.

Comment: You mean ignore time when parsing? The answer is yes. See my updated answer!

Answer (score 1):

## Cannot Specify `0` As Literal

Your attempt to parse a string like `2011/02/14 00:00:00.000 -0800` as a date‑time is a [Catch‑22](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22_(logic)).

Firstly, you cannot use a parsing pattern of `yyyy/MM/dd 00:00:00.000 Z` because there is no parsing pattern code for a zero. The character `0` has no meaning as a code.

Secondly, you might think of adding single-quote-marks around the time portion, like this: `yyyy/MM/dd '00:00:00.000' Z`, to tell the formatter to expect that string literal of an all-balls zero time value. While you *can* tell the formatter to expect a such a string, the problem is that a string‑literal is ignored semantically. So now you have no input for the time-of-day value. With a date but no time the parsing of a date‑time can not be completed. An Exception is thrown.

## Solution: Parse as time-of-day

The solution is for to change your mindset. Realize that you could receive as input any time-of-day, not necessarily all-balls zeros.

Be aware: Even if you are sure you will always get an input of the first moment of the day, that does not always mean all zeros! In some time zones the first moment of the day is *not* always `00:00:00.000` because of [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) or other anomaly.

So, just tell the formatter to parse the zeros as any valid time-of-day. Notice the `HH:mm:ss.SSS` used in the parsing pattern in sample code below.

## java.time

I do not know what `Date` class you refer to in your Question.

Anyways, you should be using the [java.time](http://r.duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2F8%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2Fjava%2Ftime%2Fpackage-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later. See [Tutorial](https://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2Ftutorial%2Fdatetime%2FTOC.html). These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as java.util.Date/.Calendar.

In particular you want the [`java.time.OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) class as it represents a moment on the timeline with a particular [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). If you had a full time zone rather than merely an offset, you would use [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

Just for fun, the example code also uses an [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html), a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FCoordinated_Universal_Time). Conceptually, an `Instant` underlies both `OffsetDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime`.

Important: The parsing codes in java.time are similar to the old java.text.SimpleDateFormat codes, but are not exactly the same. Be sure to read the doc for [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2F8%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2Fjava%2Ftime%2Fformat%2FDateTimeFormatter.html).

```
String input = "2011/02/14 00:00:00.000 -0800";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS X" );
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse ( input , formatter );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "input: " + input + " | odt: " + odt + " | instant: " + odt.toInstant () );
```

> input: 2011/02/14 00:00:00.000 -0800 | odt: 2011-02-14T00:00-08:00 | instant: 2011-02-14T08:00:00Z

The strings generated as output default to standard [ISO 8601](https://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FISO_8601) formats. If you desire another format, define and pass another [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).